# Simple example of a mapping between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I read the definition of a continuous function between topological spaces a lot of times, but I'm having difficulties to apply it to a simple example.

Given two topological spaces $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$, i.e.

$$ X=\{a,b,c\}, \tau_1=\{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{c\},\{b,c\},\{b\} \} $$
$$ Y=\{d,e,f\}, \tau_2=\{Y,\emptyset,\{d,e\},\{f\},\{e,f\},\{e\} \} $$

What would be an example of a continuous function (if any exists) $f:X \rightarrow Y$?

Wiki says:

> A function f : X→ Y between topological spaces is called continuous
>   if for all x ∈ X and all neighbourhoods N of f(x) there is a
>   neighbourhood M of x such that f(M) ⊆ N.

Here I have trouble understanding what is meant by this definition. Does $x \in X $ refer to elements of my topology $\tau_1$/ $\tau_2$ or elements of $X$/$Y$?

Let's say I map elements of $\tau_1$ to elements of $\tau_2$ like this: 
$$ \{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{d,e,f\}$$
$$ \{a,b\}\rightarrow \{d,e\} $$
$$\{c\} \rightarrow \{f\}$$
$$\{b,c\}\rightarrow\{e,f\}$$
$$\{b\}\rightarrow\{e\} $$

Would this be correct? And how can I check if this mapping is continuous? Or in other words, what is a neighborhood of a set in the topologies, e.g. what is a neighborhood of $\{a,b,c\}$ or a neighborhood of $ \{e\} $?

Well, I'm quite confused about all this, so a simple example would be nice to help me get less confused :).

Comment: Well, this is a dumb example perhaps, but the identity map from $X$ to $X$ (endowed with the same topology for domain and image) is continuous.

Comment: I don't see how you can be confused about the notation $x\in X$ : isn't it perfectly clear that $x$ is supposed to be an element of $X$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you gave is the definition for a function to be continuous at a point. The usual definition for a function to be continuous (which is equivalent with $f$ being continuous at every point) is that

> $f$ is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open.

It is easy to see, by the way you constructed your example, that indeed it is continuous.

Comment: Well, this definition I certainly understand :). But is it possible to define a function based on the definition above as well with regard to my example?

Comment: Sure, if you take as the definition that $f$ is continuous that it is continuous at each point. For each point in $Y$, look at the inverse images of each open set containing that point and check that they are open in $X$.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I don't get somehow :(. Can you maybe give a simple example based on the above sets (if possible)?

Comment: Take, for example, the element $e \in Y$. All of the open sets containing $e$ are the sets $Y$, $\{e\}$, $\{e,f\}$ and $\{d,e\}$. The inverse images of each of these sets are, respectively, $X$, $\{b\}$, $\{b,c\}$, and  $\{b,c\}$, which are all open sets in $X$. By the way, you should define the function on $X$, not on the open sets. That is, the function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is the function that maps $f(a) = d, f(b) = e,$ and $f(c) = f$.

Comment: Got it :), thank you very much!